# PHP - MySQLI INSERT INTO não funciona

Tags: php, mysql

$conexao

cadastrando.php

    
    
        Calma aí

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

$result_usuario = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO agendass(nome, email, sexo, nascimento, telefone)
VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$sexo', $nascimento, $telefone)");
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario);

echo ("$resultado_usuario");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

erro no PHPStorm: unable to resolve table 'agendas' e a mesma coisa porém unable em todas as tabelas.

na página detalha esse erro:

```
`Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjetoAgenda\template\cadastrando.php on line 23`
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$conexao

<?php

function conectar(){
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "bhideki", "1233", "agendas");
    return $con;
}

$conexao = conectar();

?>
```